# Cakephp 2.3 beforeFilter and implementedEvents aren't able to co-exist

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Using cakephp 2.3.5.

I use beforeFilter in several controllers to allow certain actions without the need to log in. I've used it successfully for quite some time. However, I've noticed that I can't get beforeFilter to fire if the controller also has the implementedEvents() method.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('matchWwiProducts');
}     

public function implementedEvents() {
       return array(
                    'Controller.Product.delete' => 'deleteSku',
                    'Controller.Product.price'  => 'notifySubscribers',
                    'Controller.Product.stock'  => 'notifySubscribers'
       );
}
```

For the code as displayed above I will be forced to do a login if I call the method www.example.com/products/matchWwiProducts.

When I comment out the implementedEvents() everything works as intended. I've searched around and can't find any references to implementedEvents() creating issues with beforeFilter.

The action matchWwiProducts() is as follows. It works perfectly when I log in. However, I don't want to force a log in for this action to take place.

```
public function matchWwiProducts() {
     // this is an audit function that matches Products sourced by wwi
     //
     $this->autoRender = false; // no view to be rendered
     // retrieve products sourced from wwi from Table::Product
     $this->Product->contain();
     $wwiProducts = $this->Product->getWwiSkus();                        
     $wwiProductCount = count($wwiProducts);
     // retrieve products sourced from wwi from Table:Wwiproduct
     $this->loadModel('WwiProduct');
     $this->Wwiproduct->contain();
     $wwiSource = $this->Wwiproduct->getSkuList();
     $wwiSourceCount = count($wwiSource);                        
     // identify SKUs in $wwiProducts that are not in $wwiSource
     $invalidSkus = array_diff($wwiProducts, $wwiSource);                        
     // identify SKUs in $wwiSource that are not in $wwiProducts
     $missingSkus = array_diff($wwiSource, $wwiProducts);                        
     $missingSkuDetails = array();
     foreach ($missingSkus as $missingSku) {
             $skuStockStatus = $this->Wwiproduct->getStockStatus($missingSku);
             $missingSkuDetails[$missingSku] = $skuStockStatus;
             }                        
     $email = new CakeEmail();
     $email->config('sourcewwi');
     $email->template('sourcewwiaudit', 'sourcewwi');
     if (count($invalidSkus) > 0 || count($missingSkus) > 0) {
            $email->subject('WWI Source Audit: Invalid or Missing SKUs');
            $email->viewVars(array('invalidSkus' => $invalidSkus,                                                       
                                   'missingSkuDetails' => $missingSkuDetails,
                                   'wwiProductCount' => $wwiProductCount,
                                   'wwiSourceCount' => $wwiSourceCount));
     } else {
             $email->subject('WWI Source Audit: No Exceptions');
             $email->viewVars(array('wwiProductCount' => $wwiProductCount,
                                    'wwiSourceCount' => $wwiSourceCount));
     }
     $email->send();
}
```

Comment: could you please post the `matchWwiProducts` action ?

Comment: action matchWwiProducts has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't fire because you're overloading the implementendEvents() method *without* making sure you keep [the existing events](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#428-442) there.

```
public function implementedEvents() {
       return array_merge(parent::implementedEvents(), array(
                    'Controller.Product.delete' => 'deleteSku',
                    'Controller.Product.price'  => 'notifySubscribers',
                    'Controller.Product.stock'  => 'notifySubscribers'
       ));
}
```

[Overloading in php.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php)

Check most of the base classes, Controller, Table, Behavior, Component, they all fire or listen to events. So be careful when extending certain methods there. Most simple way might to do a search for "EventListenerInterface" in all classes. A class that implements this interface is likely to implement event callbacks.

Comment: Thank you burzum for that answer. I'll test it out when I return home from my travels but it looks like it will do the trick.

Comment: Yep it works perfectly. And I now know something I didn't know before. Thanks!

Comment: This applies not only to this method this is basic OOP, you can override any method and you'll have to decide if you want to call it's parent are not.  Most of the time you want. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php Would you mind flagging the answer as correct? Thank you.

Comment: I understand the overloading of methods. In this case I didn't understand CakePHP well enough to realize that implementedEvents() was part of the  Controller Class. Never thought to look there. Thanks again for the answer. Very very helpful.

Comment: Check most of the base classes, Controller, Table, Behavior, Component, they all fire or listen to events. So be careful when extending certain methods there. Most simple way might to do a search for "EventListenerInterface" in all classes. :)